# How to have one Hibernate session per scheduled method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-scheduled

I have the following setup:

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    BatchService batchService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * ? * *")
    void tick() {
        logger.info("Beginning of a batch tick");
        batchService.refundNotAssignedVisits();
        logger.info("End of the batch tick");
    }
}
```

With `BatchService` containing the following:

```
@Service
public class BatchServiceImpl implements BatchService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    VisitService visitService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void refundNotAssignedVisits() {
        logger.info("Start automatic refund of past visits being assigned");

        Set<Visit> visits = visitService.findRefundableVisits();

        if(visits != null && visits.size() != 0) {
            logger.info("Found " + visits.size() + " visits to refund with IDs: " + visits.stream().map(x -> x.getId().toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
            visits.forEach(x -> {
                logger.info("Refunding visit with ID: " + x.getId());
                try {
                    visitService.cancel(x);
                    logger.info("Visit successfully refunded!");
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error while refunding visit...", e);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            logger.info("Found no visit to refund.");
        }

        logger.info("End of automatic refund");
    }
}
```

And the `cancel` method defined like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Visit cancel(Visit visit) throws Exception {
    // Some business logic
}
```

I need the `cancel` method to have one transaction per call, for business purposes, and at the moment, the `refundNotAssignedVisits` is `@Transactional` in order to enable a Hibernate session so I am able to use lazy loading with related entities in the `cancel` method.

This causes problems such as duplicate commits and I'm wondering what's a good pattern to achieve what I want: have a `@Scheduled` method that enables a Hibernate session in order to make multiple calls to another method with one transaction per call.

Comment: Did I understand you right: currently it is possible for method `tick` to run twice at the same time and you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional` 's `REQUIRES_NEW` will create another new Hibernate session , so the session inside `cancel()` will be different from the session that is used to load the entities which seems like awkward to me. Normally , we use the same session for loading and managing the same entity within a transaction.

I will refactor the codes into the followings :

`VisitService`:

```
//Cannel by visitorId and load the Visitor by Id in a new transaction
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Visit cancel(Integer visitorId) throws Exception {
    Visit visit=  session.get(Visit.class , visitorId); 
    cancel(visit); 
}

@Override
public Visit cancel(Visit visit) throws Exception {
    // Some business logic
}

//Add method to return the IDs only
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Set<Integer> findRefundableVisitId(){

}
```

BatchService:

```
//@Transactional  (Do not require anymore)
public void refundNotAssignedVisits() {
    logger.info("Start automatic refund of past visits being assigned");

    Set<Integer> refundVisitIds = visitService.findRefundableVisitId();
    refundVisitIds.forEach( id-> {
           try {
                visitService.refund(id);
                logger.info("Visit successfully refunded!");
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error while refunding visit...", e);
            }        
     });
}
```

In this way , each refund is executed in their own transaction and the transaction that is used to load the refund visitors do not need to wait for all refund complete in order to commit and no more "duplicate commits".

Comment: This looks clean to me, will try as soon as I can. Can you confirm that findRefundableVisitId and cancel will share the same session?

Comment: No they are at the separate session but it does not matter. The point is we make sure that load and cancel" the visitor using the same session which are done in the  `VisitService.cancel(vistorId)` .

Comment: I read your solution more carefully and it won't work in my case because I need to pass the visit entity. Indeed, I load related entities in the cancel method. I've added this precision in my question

Comment: That 's why I suggest you to load the visit entity and its related entities in the cancel method which is under the same transaction to make sure that the same session is always use to load and update them...

Comment: That means load every entity once to get the Id and once in thé cancel method?

Comment: Yes. The idea is first find out all the "entity Id" that need to be `cancel()` first . Actually ,you just need to load the "entity Id" first ...

Comment: Can you explain why I can't have one session per scheduled task like the session per request?

Comment: This is how spring  `@Transactional` works. If it is `REQUIRES_NEW` , it will always create a new session to start a new TX. So basically , you want to have  one session to cancel all the visit but each visit still run in their own TX ?  If yes , I doubt that if `@Transactional` can achieve it . You most probably need to directly  use hibernate 's native API in order to have the most of the flexibility to control the TX behaviour...